# Пытаюсь сделать слайд шоу по нажатию кнопки в unity , но просвечивает панель

Tags: c#, unity3d

Недавно на этом форуме я получил скрипт слайдшоу. Для главного меню он подошел, но когда я попытался использовать его в качестве кат сцены , панель начала просвечиваться сквозь кадры. Как это можно исправить ?
Скрипт слайдшоу:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BackGround : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer[] renderers;
    public float speed;
    private float a;
    private int i, l;
    private void Start()
    {
        l = renderers.Length - 1;
        for (int e = 1; e < l + 1; e++) renderers[e].color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, renderers[e].color.a);
    }
    private int getI(int v)
    {
        if (v < l) return v + 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (a < 254)
        {
            a += speed;
            renderers[i].color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, speed / 255f);
            renderers[getI(i)].color += new Color(0, 0, 0, speed / 255f);
        }
        else
        {
            if (i < l) i++;
            else i = 0;
            a = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Просвечивания панели :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2FoG.jpg)
Как это можно исправить ?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `if (v < l) return v + 1`, `if (i < l) i++` что такое v, l, i абсолютно непонятно, вы экономите символы? Никто не будет сидеть и искать в коде, что означают эти буквы. Скорее всего, у вас значение альфа канала в изображении не установлено на максимум, ищите место, где изменяется это значение и исправляйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, но думаю что вместо "speed" надо использовать "a", так как именно она изменяется, то есть должно быть вот так:

```
if (a < 254)
{
     a += speed;
     renderers[i].color -= new Color(0, 0, 0, a / 255f);
     renderers[getI(i)].color += new Color(0, 0, 0, a / 255f);
}
```